# Find Largest Value in pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

I have tried to filter a pivot table in Excel using VBA.

I need filter caller name by number of count means how many ticket they raised in month. So I used pivot table for that but I need now to find max 10 value from this pivot table means who raised maximum ticket in month.

Please see below code which gives the error:

> Runtime Error 1004: Unable to get the PivotTables property of the
>   Worksheet class

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable19").PivotFields("Caller").AutoSort _
        xlDescending, "C`enter code here`ount of Number", 
          ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable19"). _
           PivotColumnAxis.PivotLines(1), 1
```